# Include only part of a figure caption within a textbox in a table of figures in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, caption

I am writing a thesis paper with long figure captions.  I have discovered how to use Style Separator to have only the first sentence appear in the list of figures, however all my captions are in text boxes, and Style Separator does not seem to work in those.

Does anyone know of a way to get this result within a text box?  I'm using Word 2007.

Comment: Not sure about this, but can you insert a Word Field into the text box? If so, you can use the TC Field which I think still works in 2007?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have any luck with fields, but I learned some new things.  I also figured out that while I cannot insert a Style Separator, I can cut and paste one into the text box, which is just as easy, I guess.  It works.

Comment: OK, nice one. Why don't you add your own answer. You can then accept it (I think you may need to leave 24hrs first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style Separators can be inserted into regular text and then cut and pasted into the text box, giving the same effect.