# How can I hide part of a caption in the document but show it in the contents?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, field-codes, caption

I have the inverse problem to [this user](https://superuser.com/questions/287829/how-can-i-include-only-part-of-an-image-caption-in-a-table-of-figures-in-microso). I have a lot of figures that have the same caption. This makes the figure contents table look pretty repetitive and uninformative, like this:

[Image of the figure contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P9AT.png)

I want to add additional detail to the auto-generated contents table without this being visible in the captions, because there isn't enough space. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use field codes. For each figure, you can position the cursor at the end of the caption line, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a field. Between the braces (`{ }`), type `TC "Figure` followed by a space. Next press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a new field inside the first field. Between the new braces, type `SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \c`. This will grab the figure number that Word autogenerated for the caption. Now, after the closing brace for the `SEQ` field, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (since your screen shot shows that you want the figure number and the caption text to be separated by a tab space), and type the caption text as you want it to appear in the Table of figures. Finally, type `" \f F \l "1"`. For example, if I want the caption that appears below the figure to say 'The xxx menu,' but the Table of figure to show 'The xxx menu in the yyy program,' I would use this:

`{ TC "Figure { SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \c }   The xxx menu in the yyy program" \f F \l "1"}`

[image: Figure with caption and TC field]

Do this for every captioned figure in your document. (You can copy and paste the entire `TC` field, including the braces, and then change just the text that should appear in the Table of figures. All the numbering will be corrected when you update field codes later.)

Then, position the cursor in the location where you want the Table of figures to appear, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a field. Between the braces, type `TOC \f F \h \z`.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole document, and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update all field codes.

Here's the Table of figures that I ended up with after adding a caption and `TC` field to another figure in my document.

[image: Completed Table of figures]

And actually, if you want the chapter number prefixed to the figure number, with a period as the delimiter, as your screen shot shows, you'll need to add another field before the `SEQ` field (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), and type `STYLEREF 1 \s` between the braces. Then, between the closing brace for the `STYLEREF` field and the opening brace of the `SEQ` field, type a period. For example:

`{ TC "Figure { STYLEREF 1 \s }.{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \c } The xxx menu in the yyy program" \f F \l "1"}`

[image: Table of figures with chapter numbers]

Comment: Great answer, thank you I've learned a lot. I've tried to follow it in my document but it seems the doc is based on a corporate template that does not follow best practice, as it has several TOCs but doesn't use the \f switch to identify which is which. My field codes look like:
`Figure { STYLEREF 1 \S } { SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \s 1 }`
Anything in a TC field doesn't show up in the TOC. I've tried several other ways based on this but no luck, think I'll have to keep it as  it is :(

Comment: To insert the table, are you manually inserting the `TOC` field as I describe, or are you clicking a button on the **References** tab? If the latter, are you clicking **Table of Contents** or **Insert Table of Figures**? You should click **Table of Figures**. Then, click **Options**, and select the **Table entry fields** check box. Even then, I found that every figure was listed twice, so I had to select the table, right-click, click **Toggle Field Codes**, and then delete `\c "Figure"` from the end of the field code.

Comment: Works very well for me. However, the numbering for the `field codes` doesn't work for me, specifically this part: `{ SEQ Figure \* ARABIC \c }`. Instead of using that code, I am instead using this `{ SEQ Lampiran \* ARABIC }` which I copied from the original caption with the field codes autogenerated by Word. However, for some reason, the numbering does not appear on my Table of Figures. I have set my caption number to font -> hidden. Might this be the case?

Comment: Right now, I'm not using field codes to generate the numbering of the caption. I'm just using `{TC "Lampiran 1 SOME LABEL" \f F \1 "1"}` instead.