# Style Separator in Microsoft Word creates new paragraph

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2011

I am working on an MS Word document (version 2011 for Mac), and would like to create a table of figures but only use part of the text in each figure description under its respective image.

What I have: `(Image): Figure 1 - This is figure one it is all about blah blah blah`

What I want in the ToF: `Figure 1 - This is figure one`

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/287829/how-can-i-include-only-part-of-an-image-caption-in-a-table-of-figures-in-microso) it is suggested to simply insert a style separator at the point where one wants to cut off the text to show or not show. To do this it suggests to use the command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, when I use this command, it inserts the style separator but also pushes the second half of text to the next line. Like so:

```
(Image) Figure 1 - This is figure one¶
it is all about blah blah blah
```

I have no success to figure out how to make it so that the second half of the text doesn't return to the next line, but instead looks like so:

```
(Image) Figure 1 - This is figure one¶it is all about blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you used an answer for the Windows version on your Mac version, not realising that Microsoft doesn't do its business like this :)

I'm not really sure but the combination is not the same since the keys `CTRL` and `ALT` in Mac operate differently than their counterpart in Windows, so you end typing carriage return in your case.

However, here's a workaround from [this webpage](http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/RunInSidehead.htm)

> **TC fields**
>
> The oldest and often still best solution is to use a TC field. Word’s
>   Help (under “Field codes: TC (Table of Contents Entry) field”) is
>   pretty good on this subject, too. You insert a field in the paragraph
>   (immediately preceding or following the heading portion is a
>   reasonable place, but anywhere that is bound to be on the same page
>   with the heading will do), specifying the text you want to appear in
>   the TOC and the appropriate level. In the case of the example heading,
>   that field would look like this:
>
> `{ TC "But now you want a Heading 3 that is part of a text paragraph" \l 3 }`

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I wouldn't even bother with the style separator approach. As Sanny's reply notes, the best approach is to use `TC` fields. In that case, the solution is the same as my solution to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1162904/how-can-i-hide-part-of-a-caption-in-the-document-but-show-it-in-the-contents), except that you want the longer text in the caption and the shorter text in the Table of figures, not vice versa – an easy adjustment to make; the basic steps will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

With show/hide ¶ enabled, highlight the ¶ character at the end of your caption, then click Format > Font... and in the Effects section, select Hidden.

This will show as a new line while ¶ are visible, but will collapse onto the same line with this setting disabled.

Then on your list of figures, click to update the field.